# React Native generates the same apk file

Tags: android-studio, react-native, apk

**React Native**, How to clean up my project ? as after apk generation I am getting the old version of APK file.

New changes are not applied to the new generated APK all the time I am getting the same apk file.

FYI I am using Android studio. I have tried to clean up the project but results are not changed.

Comment: Are you building the APK through Android Studio? If so, just run `cd android && gradlew assembleRelease` on your terminal and you're good to go

Comment: That command will bundle your JS code before building the APK file. (Please note that that way, you're going to have to manually sign your app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go to your project folder then run the react-native bundle command then generate the apk.

**Steps to generate bundle**

```
cd /folder/yourproject/
```

Then run

```
sudo react-native bundle --platform android --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --dev false --reset-cache --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Create assets folder inside android/app/main/src/ folder if `command fails` with error:  folder doesn't exists.

After this command runs successfully now you can generate the updated apk file